# Load set through properties file

Tags: java, spring, collections, properties, set

Is it possible to load a set, which is initialised in my Spring context, with entries configured in a properties file? If so, how?

The loading of the properties file should as well happen in the Spring context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a [PropertyOverrideConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyOverrideConfigurer.html) you can initialise an array, a list or a map. That's sufficient for me.

```
myBean.myList[0]=Michael
myBean.myList[1]=J
myBean.myList[2]=Fox
```